# Problem with new inputs and focus attribute JS

Tags: javascript, function, input, focus

I created a  simple program that if I click a button, it actives the following function. I need to autofocus the new inputs. I tried it with the function `focus()` but it doesn`t work.

```
function moreInput() {
    let line = document.createElement("input");
    line.focus();
    line.classList.add("d-flex");
    line.classList.add("mt-3");
    line.classList.add("added-input");
    line.placeholder = "Nome studente";
    space.appendChild(line);
}
```

Comment: you need to focus it AFTER you add it. Move that line to the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not focus it until it is added to the DOM and is visible. So move it to the end after you append it.

```js
var space = document.body

function moreInput() {

  let line = document.createElement("input");
  line.classList.add("d-flex");
  line.classList.add("mt-3");
  line.classList.add("added-input");
  line.placeholder = "Nome studente";
  space.appendChild(line);
  line.focus();

}

moreInput()
```